How to show Geometric Brownian motion is not a Gaussian process?
Let's consider Geometric Brownian motion:
$$
X_t = e^{\mu t + \sigma B_t}
$$
where $B_t$ is Brownian motion.
Question: How to prove that this process is not Gaussian?
I understand that $B_t$ itself is Gaussian and what Gaussian process means. For some other processes (Brownian bridge, Brownian motion with drift) I showed Gausian-nes by proving a linear map between $B_t$ and $X_t$. Please suggest other ways of showing some process being Gaussian or not.
My initial intuition is that $X_t$ itself is not Gaussian due to non-symmetric distribution of values after exponentiation. However, I am not sure how to formalise it or if is valid approach.

All finite-dimensional projections of it would be (multivariate) normally distributed. Is $X_0$ normally distributed?

Also, one can check the covariance of the $X_t$ process.

Positive random variables are not normaly distributed.

@geetha290krm but process can have positive mean with very small variance?

Don't overthink too much : the process $\ln X_t = \mu t + \sigma B_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu t, \sigma^2t)$ is gaussian as a linear transformation of $B_t$; in consequence, $X_t$ follows a log-normal distribution.
